# GCC для MACOS (Macbook Air)

Tags: c++, mac, компилятор

Нужно не большое по весу решение, то есть Хсоde не подойдет, для компиляции С++ кода на Mac.
Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: а в чём проблема поставить g++ консольный и собирать с него?

Answer (score 0):

Вам может подойти Visual Studio Code

Вот тут подробно как настроить (на английском):

https://medium.com/audelabs/c-development-using-visual-studio-code-cmake-and-lldb-d0f13d38c563

Альтернативы:

1. [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) (всего 147 Мб), практически ничего настраивать не надо.
2. [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)

Если не хочется возиться с настройкой, рекомендую Netbeans.